# Julia package load extremely slow in first run

Tags: performance, package, julia

I'm using Julia 1.5.2 under Linux 5.4.0 and waited around 15 minutes for `Pkg.add("DifferentialEquations")`. Then I started the Kernel in Jupyter Notebook and ran the following code. It took terribly 1 minute to execute (the actual first time that I did this it took 225s).

```
t = time()
using Printf
using BenchmarkTools
using OrdinaryDiffEq
using Plots
tt = time() - t
@sprintf("It took %f seconds to import Printf, BenchmarkTools, OrdinaryDiffEq and Plots.", tt)
# It took 58.545894 seconds to import Printf, BenchmarkTools, OrdinaryDiffEq and Plots.
```

Finally, I done the same as above, but for each package. This is the summary:

```
Printf:           0.004755973815917969
BenchmarkTools:   0.06729602813720703
Plots:            19.99405598640442
OrdinaryDiffEq:   19.001102209091187
```

I know from [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/24827) that `Pkg` was slow in the past, but I think that 15 minutes isn't a normal installing time at all. However, this is not my big problem.

I know that Julia needs to compile everything everytime the Kernel is started or some package is loaded. But it obviously is not a compilation time, it's a compilation eternity.

Can anyone figure out why this is so terribly slow? And, if it's normal, wouldn't it be better to provide precompiled packages to `Pkg` such as `numpy` and friends are in Python? Or at least compile forever in the first `using`?

Thank you!

---

My complete Platform Info:

```
Julia Version 1.5.2
Commit 539f3ce943 (2020-09-23 23:17 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6100U CPU @ 2.30GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-9.0.1 (ORCJIT, skylake)
```

Comment: Can you try this on a nightly build? It should be much faster (my guess would be 15 seconds total)

Comment: Also, do you have a mechanical hard drive or SSD? These times seem slow even for 1.5.

Comment: @OscarSmith, I'll try it in a while, thank you.

Comment: @OscarSmith I have a SSD (not the fastest at all, but acceptable).

Comment: @OscarSmith, it diminished the loading time of Plots to about 6.2s. Thank you again.

Answer (score 6):

This problem is generally called *latency* or *time-to-first-plot (TTFP)* when referring to **julia-lang**. There are some discussions you can find when using these keywords.

A nice recent analysis of this problem is assessed in the article ["Analyzing sources of compiler latency in Julia: method invalidations"](https://julialang.org/blog/2020/08/invalidations/)

At the time of writing (end 2020, stable release v1.5.3), no general solution is available but strategies of massive precompilation of packages instead of JIT is discussed, with marginal success.