# Package loading time increases dramatically when changing Julia DEPOT_PATH

Tags: performance, julia

I'm new to Julia and, after [a suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64584575/julia-package-load-extremely-slow-in-first-run), I started using nightly build `1.6.0-DEV.1371` due to the high loading time of packages in Julia 1.5.2.

So I tried to change the default directory of `DEPOT_PATH` and copied all files from `~/.julia` to `/opt/julia` (owned by my user). Now, if I start Julia using the default directory and run the code below, it takes about 4 seconds. However, when I start julia in the new directory (`JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=/opt/julia julia`), the same code takes incredible 83 seconds. The same happens with Julia 1.5.2 (17s in the default directory, 200s in the new directory).

This is the code I'm using to measure the time.

```
t = time(); using Plots; time() - t
```

Is there some explanation about this strange (and annoying) behavior?

---

My Platform Info:

```
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6100U CPU @ 2.30GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-9.0.1 (ORCJIT, skylake)
```

And I'm using a SSD.

Comment: This is quite surprising. I know it may be a lot to ask of a new user, but can you try `using Profile, ProfileView; @profview using Plots` and see if hovering over various bars reveals a clue? You'll want to open two terminals and do this twice to do a side-by-side comparison of the "fast" version vs the "slow" version.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good chance that now you are having files from your previous Julia installation with the new Julia's `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH`. The normal approach is to set `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` to an empty folder and then install them there.

Regarding startup times there are the following things you can do:

1. Precompile package (this is also happening when you use a new version of the package for the first time)

```
using Pkg
pkg"precompile"
```

Once `Plots` is precompiled it still takes around 10s to load each time.

2. If the above time is unacceptable build-in your `Plots` into Julia system image.

```
using PackageCompiler
create_sysimage(:Plots, sysimage_path="sys_plots.so", precompile_execution_file="precompile_plots.jl")
```

For the `precompile_plots.jl` you could use commands that you use regularly or perhaps test sets from Plots.jl.

Once done you will be starting Julia with the following comand:

```
julia --sysimage sys_plots.so
```

Building the system image takes long, however once done, loading Plots.jl will be a matter of milliseconds.

More information can be found here:

- package compiler tutorial https://julialang.github.io/PackageCompiler.jl/dev/examples/plots/
- excellent tutorial video https://live.juliacon.org/talk/Z8TE39

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm already using PackageCompiler (I found it after my last question). My problem is that the loading time increases enormously when I change DEPOT_PATH, and I would like to understand why. I tried to clean the new DEPOT_PATH and install some package again, but it never finishes downloading (I tried with Plots and DifferentialEquations, neither works)…

Comment: *"but it never finishes downloading..."* - this looks like a network issue. I have been installing Julia to an empty JULIA_DEPOT_PATH folder and it always work.

Comment: I can install any package within the default directory, but when I try with the new path it doesn't work.